# using result of main query as column name in sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use result cell of main query in subquery.

I have two tables

first table is telephone

| id | name | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | raj | Jan_2021 |
| 152 | danny | Feb_2021 |

second table is ss

| id | Jan_2021 | Feb_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | 2500 | 2200 |
| 152 | 1000 | 500 |

Mysql query iam using

```
SELECT 
name,
id,
month,
(   select SOD.month 
    from ss 
    where Empid=SOD.eid
) as ava 
FROM 
telephone as SOD 
join ss 
on SOD.id=ss.Emp_id
```

but i am not getting the exact result what i want .
please help me to get this result from this tables

| id | name | month | ava |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | raj | Jan_2021 | 2500 |
| 152 | danny | Feb_2021 | 500 |

Comment: Please review column names for the tables. Looks like the columns in your table and your query don't match.

Comment: @RameshNayak sir I cant get what you are saying.

Comment: Is `Jan_2021, Feb_2021` really the column names? I mean, in 10 years time you will have 120 columns!

Comment: @Charlieface sir I want to maintain summary sheet of all employees month wise. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In rows? Exactly like you have it in your expected result, unpivoted. You need an `employee` table, and a `summary` table with FK referencing the first

Comment: I have answered the question. However, as @Charlieface mentioned, you will need to change your solution structure. Please try using the key value pair approach when the key is the month-year and value is the amount.

Comment: What happens in March?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the answer in the fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c62c/7

```
select tel.id,tel.name,tel.month,
case
when tel.month='jan_2021' then ss.jan_2021
when tel.month='feb_2021' then ss.feb_2021
when tel.month='mar_2021' then ss.mar_2021
end
as monthly
from telephone tel,ss 
where tel.id=ss.id
```

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this with `JOIN` and conditional logic:

```
select t.*
       (case t.month when 'jan_2021' then ss.jan_2021
             t.month when 'feb_2021' then ss.feb_2021
             t.month when 'mar_2021' then ss.mar_2021
        end) as monthly
from telephone t join
     ss 
     on t.id = ss.id
```

Comment: Downvoting this answer, when the other answer uses archaic syntax just looks really awkward.